# How can I completely uninstall wagtail from my system?

Tags: python, django, pip, wagtail

I ran this command:

```
pip uninstall wagtail
```

> Uninstalling wagtail: Proceed (y/n)? y
>    Successfully uninstalled
>   wagtail

However when I then ran `pip install wagtail` i received the following message:

```
root@daap:/usr/lib/python2.7# pip install wagtail
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wagtail in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django<1.11,>=1.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-modelcluster<4.0,>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-taggit<1.0,>=0.20 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-treebeard<5.0,>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): djangorestframework>=3.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow>=2.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4>=4.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): html5lib<1,>=0.999 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Unidecode>=0.04.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Willow<0.5,>=0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests<3.0,>=2.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2015.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-modelcluster<4.0,>=3.0->wagtail)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from html5lib<1,>=0.999->wagtail)
Cleaning up...
```

I am having problems that wagtail is not found when I run my django app, so I would like to completely uninstall it, then install it again.

Why isn't it being removed when I run `pip uninstall wagtail`? and how can I completely remove it? thanks

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? Because if you are then I can see that you installed wagtail outside of virtualenv and running django inside of virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks @nomad yes that was the issue. For some reason when I run pip uninstall wagtail outside the virtualenv, and then run pip install wagtail, again outside the virtualenv, it picks up the wagtail installed in the virtualenv as being active, even though im outside the virtualenv, and it says it's already installed. If I uninstall from the virtualenv also, then when im outside of the virtualenv, and try to install wagtail again, now it installs. I'm still having the same problem which is when I try to launch the django app , it says wagtail isn't installed, even if i have it in both

Comment: virtualenv, and outside of virtualenv, which is what I was hoping I would fix by uninstalling it and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

`pip` caches the python package. If you do not want to use the cache, you should use `--no-cache-dir`.

like this.

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -I wagtail
```

see also https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching

The cache dir is also written in this URL:)

Answer (score 0):

```
source your-venv\bin\activate
pip install wagtail, django
```

To uninstall, make sure you have your venv activated. Just being in the dir does not mean you are inside virtualenv.